# Changing Location of SubreportObject Object, Crystal Reports, C#

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, subreport

I am facing such kind of problem. I am using Visual Studio 2005. I need to change location of a SubreportObject object.

```
foreach (Section section in report.Sections)
{
      foreach (object obj in section.ReportObjects)
      {
          if (obj is SubreportObject)
          {
              SubreportObject sub = obj as SubreportObject;
              ReportDocument doc = sub.OpenSubreport(sub.SubreportName);
              sub.Left = Math.Max(0, width - sub.Left - sub.Width);
          }
      }
}
```

But I am getting exception because "Adding or changing this kind of report object is not supported" as the exception says. Are there any other ways for changing the location of SubReport object ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I changed the design of report and no need for changing location.